# Creating a vector in R (Associative array)

Tags: r, arrays, list, associative-array

I know I can create an array in R like this:

```
     vec <- c(a=1,b=2,c=3)
     vec["b"]
     #b 
     #2
```

what I have is a list like this:

```
> traits
[1] STD V1  V2  V3  W1  W2  W3 
Levels: STD V1 V2 V3 W1 W2 W3
```

what i want ot to create and associative array

```
    AA<- c(STD=0,V1=0,V2=0,V3=0,W1=0,W2=0,W3=0)
```

then latter on I can update the array AA("STD")=1 or whatever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could try

```
setNames(rep(0, length(traits)), levels(traits)[traits])
STD  V1  V2  V3  W1  W2  W3 
  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

#### data

```
traits <- factor(c("STD", "V1", "V2", "V3", "W1", "W2", "W3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try -

```
traits <- factor(letters[1:3])
AA <- setNames(numeric(length(x)), x)
AA

#a b c 
#0 0 0
```